# Javascript / Firefox width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

You can view the issue here, controls with left and right arrow.
http://onezeromany.com/cv/
(works fine in chrome/safari, not in firefox)

I have 9 divs, all full size of the browser window. They act as slides, as you can see in the demo. Now, for some reason in Firefox they slide a bit further to the left, every time again. Is this a known issue, somebody know the solution? Here's the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var slide = 1;
        var browserwidth = -$(window).width() -1;
        $("body").children().not("#slide1").css("left",Math.abs(browserwidth));

        $(document).keydown(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 37) {
                if(slide > 1) {
                    slide--;
                    $("#slide" + slide).animate({left:"0px"}, 500, "linear");
                    $("#slide" + (slide + 1)).animate({left:Math.abs(browserwidth)}, 500, "linear");
                }
            }
            if(e.keyCode == 39) {
                if(slide < 9) {
                    $("#slide" + slide).animate({left:browserwidth}, 500, "linear");
                    $("#slide" + (slide + 1)).animate({left:0}, 500, "linear");
                    slide++;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to use it with the left and right arrow.

Comment: When you inspect the DOM in the various browsers, are the width values consistent with each other?

Comment: Looking at the page, you're running different code in "Firefox" and in other browsers.  Is the question why the behavior is different given that, or was the behavior different before you started serving different code to Firefox?

Comment: The behavior was different before I used different code for Firefox. Firefox moved it 16px more to the left every time, so that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Try executing on $(window).load instead of $(document).ready

Comment: What possible difference would that make?

Comment: $(document).ready triggers as soon as the DOM is ready. $(window).load triggers when all elements and objects are completely loaded. As this relies on elements' dynamic dimensions I thought it was worth a shot. I do apologize sparky, geez.